# Making sure linux uses all my hardware correctly

Tags: linux, memory, debian

I have a new decent computer coming my way in a week or so, and I have a few worries. I never had to care about installing Linux before as all my hardware was pretty low standard, but now I'll be having decent hardware I don't want to mess anything up, and want to make sure that all my hardware is being used correctly. I am very prepared in terms of configuring things, that's one of the reasons I use Linux over Windows.

tl;dr Will a full amd64 Debian CD install be enough to use all my hardware to it's full potential, or are there things I'll have to do in order to achieve this once installed.

New comp specs:
Intel Core i5 4460 3.2GHz CPU (not necessary but I'll post it anyway),
Kingston ValueRAM 8GB DDR3 Memory (1 stick),
NVIDIA GeForce GT 720,
64bit.

Comment: One thing you can do is check at the manufacturers websites of your hardware components for the latest drivers. Btw - 1x 8GB Dimm is not as optimal as 2x4GB Dimms.

Comment: @whs Why is 1 dimm not as optimal? Based on what? As far as I know, performance wise, multiple DIMMs only benefit from multi channel slots (and only if DIMMs are multi channel, too); so 1x8GB single channel DIMM would be the same as 2x4GB DIMMs. But I may be wrong, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You are right for single channel boards. But better boards have multi channels. Maybe you want to check the specs of yours.